# Discord not sending everything out properly in a loop

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm using a web scraper and using the results from it and printing it out as a result of the discord command but I keep running into a problem where it wont send everything.

```
async def anime(ctx, *, input_by_user=None):
    animespaces = input_by_user.replace(' ', '-').lower()

    page_url  = "https://www.crunchyroll.com/" + animespaces

    uClient = uReq(page_url)

    anime_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")

    episodes = anime_soup.findAll("p", {"class": "short-desc"})

    eplist = len(episodes)
    eplist -=1
    t_end = time.time() + eplist # <--- I have even tried doing a + client.latency
                                 # While toying with it I've found that giving it more time with + fixes it sort of but in the end doesn't  work for multiple tests

    while time.time() < t_end:

        eplist -=1

        title = episodes[eplist] 

        time.sleep(1)
        eps = title.text.strip()


        await ctx.send("Episode:" + " " + eps)
# If there are 5 episodes for example it may miss the last three or 2 or just 1 for instance
# -----OUTPUT------
# Episode 1: "episode"
# Episode 2: "episode"
# Episode 3: "episode"
# Episode 4: "episode"
# ----OUTPUT_END-----
# Here is where it will just stop and wont send anything further
```

Comment: It might be the "time.sleep()" messing with your timings. Always use asyncio.sleep() in async threads.

Comment: It seems that that wasn't the issue rather whenever I include the await ctx.send("example") it seemed not to work properly and when excluded it, the console outputted it just fine. I have no clue why this like that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just looping it forever with a while True statement and just made it so when it reached 0 it stopped.

```
        eplist -=1
        title = episodes[eplist] 

        eps = title.text.strip()
        await ctx.send("Episode:" + " " + eps)
        print(eplist)
        if eplist == 0:
            break  
        else:
            print('its not done')
```